# Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL

Tags: c++, googlemock

Im new to Gmock. I try a example but it's error. I also refer a few posts on the group but it not helpul for me.

> ```
> class MATH
> {
> public:
>   virtual ~MATH(){}
>     virtual int Tong(int a, int b)
>     {
>         return a + b;
>     }
> };
>
> class MockMATH : public MATH
> {
> public:
>     MOCK_METHOD2(Tong, int(int,int));
> };
>
> class TestMATH
> {
>     MATH m ;
> public:
>     int TestTong(int a, int b)
>     {
>       cout<<"TONG"<<endl;
>         if(m.Tong(a,b))
>         {
>             cout<<"Successful"<<endl;
>             return a+b;
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             cout<<"Failed"<<endl;
>             return -1;
>         }
>
>     }
>
> };
>
> TEST(MyMathTest, Tong_by_true)
> {
>     MockMATH mM;
>     TestMATH math;
>     EXPECT_CALL(mM,Tong(_,_));
>     //.WillOnce(Return(9));
>
>     int retValue = math.TestTong(4,5);
>   std::cout<<retValue<<std::endl;
>     EXPECT_EQ(retValue,9);
> }
>
> int main(int argc, char** argv)
> { 
>   ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
>   int ret = RUN_ALL_TESTS();
>   return ret;
> }
> ```

and this error is showed below : 
[image]

Comment: `TestMATH` doesn't refer `mM`. Why do you expect `mM.Tong` is called?

Comment: I understood this issue. thank's for reply :D :D

Comment: @S.M. thanks for replied, but i have another issue. How can i mocking a method that return void by using MOCK_METHODn. I've tried MOCK_METHOD0(MethodName, void(Args)); but it's doesn't works.
And how can we testing local variables inside void function. Or a function that print out something but have not return and we need to check what it print out.

Comment: Ask this question in a new topic and I will answer on it, if don't not sleep.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is method Tong() is never called on your mock object mM. It is called on object m, member of TestMath class. That cannot work, m is not a mock object, gmock knows nothing about it and cannot track methods being called on it.

The simplest solution I see is:

```
class MATH { public: virtual ~MATH(){} virtual int Tong(int a, int b) { return a + b; } };
class MockMATH : public MATH
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD2(Tong, int(int,int));
};

class TestMATH
{
    MockMATH m ;
public:
    int TestTong(int a, int b)
    {
      std::cout<<"TONG"<<std::endl;
        if(m.Tong(a,b))
        {
          std::cout<<"Successful"<<std::endl;
            return a+b;
        }
        else
        {
          std::cout<<"Failed"<<std::endl;
            return -1;
        }

    }

    MockMATH& getMMath() { return m; }

};

TEST(MyMathTest, Tong_by_true)
{
    TestMATH math;
    EXPECT_CALL(math.getMMath(),Tong(_,_))
    .WillOnce(Return(9));

    int retValue = math.TestTong(4,5);
  std::cout<<retValue<<std::endl;
    EXPECT_EQ(retValue,9);
}
```

which passes the test.

Comment: Thanks for reply, it's worked now. But can you tell me more details about how EXPECT_CALL statement works? What args we need to pass and how Return() effect to m.Tong(a,b)?

Comment: This question is rather vague, I'd recommend you to read the docs, perhaps several times. The description there is quite clear. If you don't find an answer to some particular question there, I'd be glad to give it to you if I know it:-)